# How can I delete everything on a flash drive without actually formatting it?

Tags: fat32

I purchased a new 64 GB flash drive.  It came formatted in the FAT32 file system.  It came preloaded with some software that I don't want:

[image: contents]

However, [Windows will not format a drive larger than 32 GB in FAT32](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs--fat--and-exfat), so formatting the drive to erase the software isn't an option for me.  **How can I delete everything on the flash drive without actually formatting it?**

Obviously, one way to do it (at least in Windows 7) is:

1. In Windows Explorer, click **Organize > Folder and search options >
   View > Show hidden files, folders, and drives**.
2. Then click **Organize > Select All** and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd>
   key.

*But is there a more rigorous way to erase everything on the drive?*  I want to ensure that the preloaded software is completely gone from the drive.

Comment: Why do you want a more complicated solution then just deleting the files?

Comment: @Ramhound  I want to make sure that the software (bloatware) is completely gone from the flash drive before I back up my documents to it.

Comment: Not like it changes anything... Deleted files usually stay deleted. It's not going to automagically infect your PC.

Comment: @Andrew Removing the files will accomplish that goal

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). It formats partitions of any *technically* acceptable size as FAT32, meaning up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 blocks. It can also do a lot of other things, but that’s not relevant here.

Keep in mind that Windows’ 32 GiB limitation with FAT32 is purely a design decision. A crappy one, too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with the diskpart utility.

Open a command prompt and enter

```
diskpart
```

Then enter:

```
list disk
```

You will see a list of your drives. Enter:

```
select disk #
```

Where number is your flash drive. Next, enter:

```
clean
```

That will totally wipe the drive and anything that was on it including the partitions and file system. Afterwards, you can exit `diskpart` and the command prompt and go to the `diskmgmt` tool in Windows (it can be found in the search bar) and right click your flash drive, select `New Simple Volume`, choose NTFS as the file system, and set it up. This will prevent the formatting issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a need to keep a FAT32 filesystem, which I *highly* doubt, format the drive as NTFS.  NTFS is a much better filesystem that supports more features, faster speed, and higher security.  FAT32 is a 20+ year old filesystem, which the drive was most likely formatted as to offer compatibility to non-Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: As mentioned below, this is not effective for flash memory, I will leave this up for information purposes only.

if reformatting the drive is absolutely not an option, you can use a secure delete utility such as `srm`. It not only deletes the files, but also overwrites them so that they cannot be recovered by examining the block device. You should note that `srm` is only available for POSIX systems, so it might be worth loading up a linux live CD. Here is a link:

http://srm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Are you sure this would work on a flash drive?  the system can't force a write to a specific hardware location because that's all hidden by the controller.

Comment: I am aware that srm may not be appropriate for flash drives that have seen a lot of use because of wear-leveling techniques that will move things around. Considering that this is a new drive, I doubt that those blocks will have been copied elsewhere. As for your statement about not being able to write to specific location, I believe you are correct.